# Reply to POST request is not shown when navigating to another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, debugging, post

I am doing something on the lines:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.baseApiUrl + url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data || null,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('data=%o', data);
        window.location.reload(true);
    },
    error: function(xxx) {
        console.warn('error > xxx=%o', xxx);
    }
});
```

(I have configured Chrome to not clean the network tab or the console on navigation)

It seems that the `window.location.reload(true);`, which forces a reload of the current page, prevents Chrome from:

- collecting the reply in the Network tab. The preview / response subtabs are empty
- showing the data in the `console.log('data=%o', data);` statement. The received Object is empty

Is this a bug in Chrome, or a more general problem? Can I do something to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like some issue with Chrome rendering JSON in Console. As a workaround you can convert your JSON data to string format and log. Hopefully this should make your debug log stick

```
console.log('data=%o', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no issues dumping json to the console with chrome, *normally*. Just in this navigation scenario. I will try your suggestion, but what about the data in the network tab? I have the impression that chrome is somehow not "seeing" the data in the reply, *at all*.

Comment: Not sure which which chrome version you are using but there was an option to explictly ask about intercepting the XMLHTTPRequest. If that's the case then maybe you turn that on. Right click in console pane and it should be there.

Comment: OK, verified, your stringify works: data is logged to the console.

Comment: On the other hand, the network tab remains empty, even after enabling the intercepting of XMLHTTPRequest. It is quite interesting: if I click fast on the POST request, with the preview tab selected, while it is being executed, the data is shown. If I select the POST request when it is already complete I get a "Failed to load response data". This only happens when combined with navigation (window.location.reload)